# How to return element using part of class name

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
static get productField() {
        return element(By.className('chosen-container chosen-container-single select-products dark ng-scope ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid localytics-chosen ng-not-empty'));
    }
```

I have this field. But my issue is the class name is too long. I just want to use "select-products" from it and get rid of the remaining.

Is there a way to return element using this className parameter only with "select-products"?

Comment: You don't need to use all these classes to find element. Use as minimum as possible. Even a single class is enough to select an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return the element using the class you want. If you provide more classes, the selection will get more specific.

```
static get productField() {
    return element(By.className('select-products'));
}
```

---

#### Scope:

```
<div class="animal dog">dog</div>
<div class="animal elephant">elephant</div>
```

```
static get getAnimals() {
    return element(By.className('animal'));
}
// returns animal divs

static get getDogs() {
    return element(By.className('dog'));
}
// returns the dog div
```

Answer (score 0):

element(By.className('chosen-container chosen-container-single select-products dark ng-scope ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid localytics-chosen ng-not-empty'))

You can have something like this (use contains and the tag for xpath)

`var elementExample = element(by.xpath('//<tag>[contains(@class,"select-products")]'));`